# JavaScript how to get a length from a map array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to JSX and I am trying to get the number of Employees for each team `this.state.teams[0].employee.length` will give me the number of employee for the `[0]` object in the array, how can I get the number of employees for each Team and only render it once?

```
render() {
    const {teams, isLoading} = this.state;
    const { location } = this.props;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
    // console.log("Number of Employees team", this.state.teams[0].employee.length);
    

    const teamList = teams.map(team => {

        console.log("TEAM Employees", teams[0].employee.length);

        return <tr key={team.id}>
               <td>
                <div className="tableContent">
                    <div>
                         {team.name} 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <ul>{team.employee.map(employee => {
                       return <li key={employee.id}>{employee.name}: {employee.email}</li>
                      })}</ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     {team.employee.map(employee => {
                       return <li key={employee.id}>{teams[0].employee.length}</li>
                      })}
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    });
```

Comment: what is `teams`?

Comment: `teams` is an array set in the `constructor` `this.state = {teams: [] }` with an api response that `setState({teams: data})`

Comment: can you give an example of the objects inside the `teams` array

Comment: this is what shows in `console.log(teams)` `0: {id:1 name: "Team1", employees: Array(2)}`

Comment: I believe doing `team.employee.length` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for a specific team:

```
const teamList = teams.map(team => {
   console.log("TEAM Employees", team.employee.length);
}
```

or this for number of employees in all teams:

```
const numberOfAllEmployees = teams.map(team => team.employee.length).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(teams[0].employee).length`

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal
> loop would. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)